# YouTube API | Extract video name, channel name and author logo

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

I need to get all the stuff I mentioned in the title, but I just can't find anything related to my search anywhere. I tried parsing the site using requests + bs4, but it didn't quite work. I couldn't find anything i wanted in the response. Then i decided to google my luck and discovered how to get a video preview from the video url. Here is the code i have now:

```
from requests import get
from furl import furl
 
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, link) -> None:
        self.__id = self.__getVideoID(link)

    def __getVideoID(self, link) -> str:
        id = furl(link).args['v']
        return id

    def downloadPreview(self, filename='test.jpg'):
        imageURL = f'https://img.youtube.com/vi/{self.__id}/maxresdefault.jpg'
        response = get(imageURL)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)

    def downloadLogo(self, filename='testLogo.jpg'):
        pass # TODO

    def getCreatorData(self) -> dict:
        pass # TODO
```

I would really appreciate any help and I'm sorry if It's a super obvious and easy question for you.

Comment: Any reason for not using YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint?

Comment: Yes, lack of knowledge about it. I'll check it out today